# Sharing arrays between threads in Rust

Tags: rust, ownership-semantics

I'm new to Rust and I'm struggling with some ownership semantics.

The goal is to do some nonsense measurements on multiplying 2 f64 arrays and writing the result in a third array.

In the single-threaded version, a single thread takes care of the whole range. In the multi-threaded version, each thread takes care of a segment of the range.

The single-threaded version is easy, but my problem is with the multithreaded version where I'm struggling with the ownership rules.

I was thinking to use raw pointers, to bypass the borrow checker. But I'm still not able to make it pass.

```
#![feature(box_syntax)]

use std::time::SystemTime;
use rand::Rng;
use std::thread;


fn main() {
    let nCells = 1_000_000;
    let concurrency = 1;

    let mut one = box [0f64; 1_000_000];
    let mut two = box [0f64; 1_000_000];
    let mut res = box [0f64; 1_000_000];

    println!("Creating data");
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    for i in 0..nCells {
        one[i] = rng.gen::<f64>();
        two[i] = rng.gen::<f64>();
        res[i] = 0 as f64;
    }
    println!("Finished creating data");

    let rounds = 100000;
    let start = SystemTime::now();
    let one_raw = Box::into_raw(one);
    let two_raw = Box::into_raw(two);
    let res_raw = Box::into_raw(res);

    let mut handlers = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..rounds {
        let sizePerJob = nCells / concurrency;
        for j in 0..concurrency {
            let from = j * sizePerJob;
            let to = (j + 1) * sizePerJob;
            handlers.push(thread::spawn(|| {
                unsafe {
                    unsafe {
                        processData(one_raw, two_raw, res_raw, from, to);
                    }
                }
            }));
        }

        for j in 0..concurrency {
            handlers.get_mut(j).unwrap().join();
        }

        handlers.clear();
    }

    let durationUs = SystemTime::now().duration_since(start).unwrap().as_micros();
    let durationPerRound = durationUs / rounds;
    println!("duration per round {} us", durationPerRound);
}

// Make sure we can find the function in the generated Assembly
#[inline(never)]
pub fn processData(one: *const [f64;1000000],
                   two: *const [f64;1000000],
                   res: *mut [f64;1000000],
                   from: usize,
                   to: usize) {
    unsafe {
        for i in from..to {
            (*res)[i] = (*one)[i] * (*two)[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting

```text
error[E0277]: `*mut [f64; 1000000]` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:38:27
    |
38  |             handlers.push(thread::spawn(|| {
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `*mut [f64; 1000000]` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `*mut [f64; 1000000]`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `&*mut [f64; 1000000]`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> src/main.rs:38:41
    |
38  |             handlers.push(thread::spawn(|| {
    |                                         ^^
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> /home/pveentjer/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/thread/mod.rs:653:8
    |
653 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`
```

[edit] I know that spawning threads is very expensive. I'll convert this to a pool of worker threads that can be recycled once this code is up and running.

Comment: If you're planning to do this for a real problem and not just practice, consider using [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/) — it provides the thread pool and also automatic subdivision of inputs for processing on threads.

Comment: It is just a toy to see how efficient Rust is and to gain some practical experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `chunks_mut` or `split_at_mut` to get non-overlapping slices of `one` `two` and `res`. You can then access different slices from different threads safely. See: [documentation for chunks_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.ChunksMut.html) and [documentation for split_at_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut)

I was able to compile it using `scoped threads` and `chunks_mut`. I have removed all the `unsafe` stuff because there is no need. See the code:

```
#![feature(box_syntax)]
#![feature(scoped_threads)]

use rand::Rng;
use std::thread;
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main() {
    let nCells = 1_000_000;
    let concurrency = 2;

    let mut one = box [0f64; 1_000_000];
    let mut two = box [0f64; 1_000_000];
    let mut res = box [0f64; 1_000_000];

    println!("Creating data");
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    for i in 0..nCells {
        one[i] = rng.gen::<f64>();
        two[i] = rng.gen::<f64>();
        res[i] = 0 as f64;
    }
    println!("Finished creating data");

    let rounds = 1000;
    let start = SystemTime::now();

    for _ in 0..rounds {
        let size_per_job = nCells / concurrency;
        thread::scope(|s| {
            for it in one
                .chunks_mut(size_per_job)
                .zip(two.chunks_mut(size_per_job))
                .zip(res.chunks_mut(size_per_job))
            {
                let ((one, two), res) = it;
                s.spawn(|| {
                    processData(one, two, res);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    let durationUs = SystemTime::now().duration_since(start).unwrap().as_micros();
    let durationPerRound = durationUs / rounds;
    println!("duration per round {} us", durationPerRound);
}

// Make sure we can find the function in the generated Assembly
#[inline(never)]
pub fn processData(one: &[f64], two: &[f64], res: &mut [f64]) {
    for i in 0..one.len() {
        res[i] = one[i] * two[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is this will still lead to some form of 'closure may outlive the current functions, but it borrows ... which is owned by the current function'

Comment: @pveentjer what if you use `crossbeam::scope`?

Comment: That goes far beyond my skill set.

Comment: @pveentjer it is similar to normal threads, but the threads are guaranteed to be joined at the end of the scope. So you can be sure that slices in the local scope will outlive the threads.

Comment: No need to use crossbeam, scoped threads are now stable.

Comment: In the original code, the processing was done in parallel. In the above example, it isn't. There is a single thread spawned per round; instead of having 'concurrency' number of threads. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @pveentjer yes you are right. Now it is correct. I just changed the place of for and spawn.